# Dynamically mess images inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, i'm starting a function to 'mess' with a image gallery, i made an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yVnTR/17/)

i wanna know if the way i'm doing is realy the BEST way, the function work perfect, but i fill that can be better, something more dynamic, like never flow over the edge, and mess with the number of images that user places inside the gallery, now i set as index 0 to 5.

Is there any easy way to improve this little function, make the code faster/smaller then that?

Any tips, be my guest.

---

### jQuery

```
$("#ran").click(function () {
    mess(1, $(".holder img"));
});

function mess(type, gallery) {
    var getNumImg = gallery.length,
        winWidht = $("#galeria").width(),
        winheight = $("#galeria").height(),
        imgHeight = $("#content-wrapper img").height(),
        ftBottom = winheight - ($(".stats").height() + imgHeight + 150);

    $(".holder").width(winWidht / 2);

    gallery.each(function (index) {
        var randonLeft, randonRight, randonTop, randonTransform, maxIndex;
        var leftFt, topFt, transFt;
        var sign = "- ";
        var signRes = sign.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * sign.length));

        if (type == 1) {
            if (index == 0) {
                maxIndex = getNumImg;
                transFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": 30
                }
                topFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": ftBottom
                }
            } else if (index == 1) {
                leftFt = {
                    "from": 30,
                    "to": 40
                }
                transFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": 30
                }
                topFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": ftBottom
                }
            } else if (index == 2) {
                leftFt = {
                    "from": -30,
                    "to": -40
                }
                transFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": 30
                }
                topFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": ftBottom
                }
            } else if (index == 3) {
                leftFt = {
                    "from": -30,
                    "to": -40
                }
                transFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": 30
                }
                topFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": ftBottom
                }
            } else if (index == 4) {
                transFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": 30
                }
                topFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": ftBottom
                }
            } else if (index == 5) {
                leftFt = {
                    "from": 40,
                    "to": 50
                }
                transFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": 30
                }
                topFt = {
                    "from": 1,
                    "to": ftBottom
                }
            }
        }

        if (typeof leftFt != "undefined") {
            randonLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * leftFt.to) + leftFt.from;
        }
        if (typeof transFt != "undefined") {
            randonTransform = Math.floor(Math.random() * transFt.to) + transFt.from;
        }
        if (typeof topFt != "undefined") {
            randonTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * topFt.to) + topFt.from;
        }

        // make it happen
        $(this).css({
            zIndex: maxIndex,
            left: randonLeft,
            top: randonTop,
            transform: "rotate(" + signRes + randonTransform + "deg)"
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Example was not working, updated right now

Comment: Quer uma resposta em Port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is good and more importantly it works. The main thing I would change is that huge if else statement. You repeat yourself a lot there. Here's another way you could do it:

Also here's your edited **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yVnTR/18/)**.

Acho que o seu trabalho está bom e mais importante ele funciona. A parte que chama minha atenção é o if/else enorme. Você se repete muito ali. Outra forma que você pode fazer é assim:

```
if(type === 1){
    //You had these every time, so you can declare them once here.
    //Você declara isso em todos os casos, mas só precisa fazer uma vez aqui.
    topFt = { "from" : 1, "to" : ftBottom };
    transFt  = { "from" : 1,  "to" : 30 };

    //I Took out all the repetitions and left the cases where we actually change something.
    //Tirei todos os casos em que você estava se repetindo e deixei somente os que realmente estão mudando algo.
    switch(index){ 
        case 0:
            maxIndex = getNumImg;
            break;
        case 1:
            leftFt   = { "from" : 30, "to" : 40 }
            break;
        case 2: //If index === 2
        case 3: //OR if index === 3
            leftFt   = { "from" : -30,  "to" : -40 }
            break;
        case 5:
            leftFt   = { "from" : 40,  "to" : 50 }
            break;
        //Add more cases if you want/need to.
        //Adicione mais casos aqui se precisar.
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```